# Want to desing a Local search engine

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to make a local search engine, Through which we can search locally.
I have the document like Main Category,Sub Category,Details about the product etc.

It works like the Justdial.com Or amlooking4.com.

So,Any one suggest any code or any reference link then it will be helpful for me.
I want to to work on this in .net environment & SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have your database where you need to perform the search, you can consider using the built-in full text search in the SQL Server. See:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/